# Is there a device which encrypts messages in a physically isolated place from the part which is used for communication?

Tags: privacy

The recent NSO scandal made me think, how could I design a system which enables encrypted communication even if the devices are use are compromised. I came up with this idea: take two Raspberry Pis or similar devices. On on of them, I physically destroy the chips which enable wireless communication, the other one I connect it to the internet. Both would have a screen and a camera. If I want to send a message to someone with the same device, I use the RP not connected directly to the internet to encrypt the message, using the recipient's public address. The encrypted message is displayed on the screen of this RP. The other RP reads the message, sends it to someone with a similar device, over the internet (this does not have to be encrypted as the message I am sending is already encrypted by the offline RP). The online RP of the recipient displays the message, the offline RP reads it, decrypts it, and viola, communication is done.

The only information which enters into the RP which has the private keys (ie the one doing the encryption) has to come through the screen, which is just displaying QR codes (if I successfully destroy the WiFi-enabling chips, of course.)

The difference between this setup and a normal communication using 1 device, is that the device which is connected to the internet (ie the one which is exposed to insecurities), is not the one which is doing the encryption, and their only connection is the QR codes displayed on the screen. Given how end-to-end encryption did not stop Pegasus, it seems like a good idea not to rely on the same device to do both encryption & communication.

[image]

What could go wrong with this setup, and has there been a similar project done before?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013790259-Using-Your-YubiKey-with-OpenPGP

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: Are you sure? It would work pretty much the same way you described, the only differences being that the transport mechanism is easier to implement (no QR-Code library or  camera needed) and a well established protocol is being used. 

I am not sure what you mean with "physically isolated place" though, what properties are you wishing to gain from this isolation? If it is just that no malicious code can be executed on the second device a yubikey would do the trick, the protocol that is used would prevent any malicious activities.

Comment: Another device family that might meet your requirements are hardware security modules.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but isn't ubikey just a hardware which I can plug into my computer (which has been & will be able to connect to the internet), and this device handles private keys? It appears to me that it does not in any way prevent my computer to connect to internet & therefore being exploited if there is a vulnerability. The information which ubikey encrypts & decripts goes through potentially vulnerable device. One of the key things I was trying to illustrate with the above drawing, is that all inputs & outputs of the encryption are handled by a device unable to connect to

Comment: the internet (the RP on the right hand side). My understanding is that there is no ubikey which works without my computer's keyboard & screen, let me know if I'm wrong here.

Comment: Another thing: ubikey does not handle communication, only encryption, as far as I know.

Comment: that's fine, i've made things like that (a QRcode "modem") before. You don't really need the 2nd pi and qr code stuff, you can encrypt on the no-wifi pi (using a shared secret) and paste the ciphertext into any messaging app. you could make the pi act like a normal PC keyboard to reduce effort. FWIW, I would use an MCU like arduino instead of a PC (pi) to reduce attack surface even more while lowering production cost.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you! Yes, arduino does seem better indeed! If I don't have shared secret, I can just input recipient's public key to the arduino and enrypt it using that key & my private key & then send that through any messaging app. Do you have any suggestion how I could "streamline" this, ie get the public key to the arduino without needing to type it every time or using an usb cable for example, which could be used for exploit, if the device running the messaging app is compromised?

Comment: i would load the credentials onto an sdcard that the Arduino can read.